# Google Sheets - Looking to hide rows after input date has passed today's date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm not at all too familiar with creating script to run in Google sheets.

But I'm looking to be able to hide any given row once the input date has passed today's date. I've attached the sheet.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uj1AAu5_79mGk7hseLSyhlnWRSuAq6I__FNWUY66_EA/edit?usp=sharing)

Would anyone be able to help me?

Comment: What's the column of the input date?

Comment: 'C' is the column of the input date, with 'C1' having a header

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function hideOldRows(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dt=new Date();
  var tdv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(new Date(vA[i][2]).valueOf()<tdv){
      sh.hideRows(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

If used with a trigger:

```
function hideOldRows(e){
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var inclA=['Patrick'];//You can add other sheet names to the included list of sheets. The function will return for other sheets on the next line.
  if(inclA.indexOf(sh.getName())==-1){return;}
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dt=new Date();
  var tdv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(new Date(vA[i][2]).valueOf()<tdv){
      sh.hideRows(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

> You can't run this function from script editor because onEdit trigger provides an event object represented by the letter e in this function which is needed for this function. Please read this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089067/7215091)

- [Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: In your script, how about modifying ``sh.hideRow(i+1)`` to ``sh.hideRows(i+1)``, because the row index is used?

Comment: Thanks for that.  I didn't realize the other was for a range.

Comment: Awesome thank you both, that actually works perfectly :)!

Comment: Is there a way to automate this instead of pressing 'run' every single time?

Comment: With a few modifications you can run it from an onEdit trigger

Comment: Thank you for script with a trigger. Would you be able to advise on what kind of modifications I might have to change to make it run from an onEdit trigger?